# Distinct Number of item by Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I a trying to select the number of cars per "Name". If I use "distinct"
I only get the number of occurrences, not good. I need to get the result as something like
this:

```
   Name    NumberOfCars
 Joe Doe         3
 Mary Lou        2
 Lou Ann         1
```

My Table/Data sample:

```
 Control#  Account#   Name    CarNumber  CarYear  CarFactory
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     1        2007 TOYOTA
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     1        2007 TOYOTA
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     1        2007 TOYOTA
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     2        2008 GMC S
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     2        2008 GMC S
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     2        2008 GMC S
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     3        2012 SPRIN
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     3        2012 SPRIN
  X1111     112233A   Joe Doe     3        2012 SPRIN
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    1        2003 JEEP
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    1        2003 JEEP
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    1        2003 JEEP
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    1        2003 JEEP
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    2        2004 TOYO
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    2        2004 TOYO
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    2        2004 TOYO
  X1111     556688B   Mary Lou    2        2004 TOYO
  Y1112     882234C   Lou Ann     2        2015 LEX
  Y1112     882234C   Lou Ann     2        2015 LEX
```

Here is my simple select, I am using SQL Server:

```
 SELECT distinct Name, CarNumber as NumberOfCars
 FROM my_table
 WHERE Control# in('X1111', Y1112)
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this?
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why is there so much duplication in your data?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to count the distinct carnumber using `group by`.

```
SELECT Name, count(distinct CarNumber) as NumberOfCars
FROM my_table
WHERE Control# in('X1111', 'Y1112')
group by name
```